# Debian apt-get repository

Tags: linux, debian, apt, repository

We have our own internal package repository hosted on a webserver running apache.

Internal users who want to install one of these packages point these sources.list to the webserver & do a apt-get update & apt-get install packgname.

One of these packages is a package called ourpkgname_1.0.0-0_all.deb

now i have made come changes and created a new updated package called ourpkgname_1.0.1-0_all.deb.

I have no idea how to remove the original package from the webserver directory & add the new version. just deleting it at the /tmp/mirror/pool etc & copying the name package doesn't work. I am assuming there is some command which i need to run to copy & regenarate anything at the repository, but don't know how to.

Can someone help or point me to the appropriate documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already have it all set up, then the steps outlined in this [blog](http://linux.koolsolutions.com/2009/09/21/howto-create-your-own-local-debian-repository/) post will probably be enough to get you going in the right direction.

Answer (score 5):

I find [reprepro](http://mirrorer.alioth.debian.org/) a great tool for this. It makes repository creation and maintenance a piece of cake. Here's some pruned instructions from the manual:

1. Decide where you will place your repository (`YOURBASEDIR=/path/to/custom/repo`).
2. Create a directory structure (`mkdir -p $YOURBASEDIR/conf`).
3. Create a text file in there (`editor $YOURBASEDIR/conf/distributions`) and add this:

   ```
   Codename: custom_repo
   Components: main
   Architectures: i386
   ```
4. Add your package:

   ```
   reprepro --basedir $YOURBASEDIR includedeb custom_repo ourpkgname_1.0.1-0_all.deb
   ```
5. Add this line to your "**/etc/apt/sources.list**":

   ```
   deb file:/path/to/custom/repo custom_repo main
   ```
6. Then the usual `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`, after which your version **1.0.1-0** is an apt-get away.

This tool is quiet capable, so if you want more than this simple use-case (e.g. if you want to import your current custom repo, or if you want to add gpg signatures), go have a look at the website and/or the manpage.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this page](http://www.isotton.com/software/debian/docs/repository-howto/repository-howto.html#id301127) in the [Debian Repository HOWTO](http://www.isotton.com/software/debian/docs/repository-howto/repository-howto.html)

HTH

Fran